# Laravel 5: how to "order by" using Eloquent ORM form exist to not exist by date

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have a table

```
id  name    publish_at    total
------------------------
1   shirt1  2000          6
2   shirt2  2019          0
3   shirt3  2010          5
4   shirt4  2019          1
```

I want sort it by pubish at and not 0 for total in laravel:

I want this:

```
shirt4
shirt3
shirt1
shirt2
```

I try this:

```
$query->orderBy('total', 'desc');
$query->orderBy('publish_at', 'desc');
```

but it sort by total and for same total sort by publish

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to call the $query again

```
        $query = Model::all()
        ->orderBy('publish_at', 'ASC')
        ->get();
        return view('view', [
        'query ' => $query 
         ]);
```

Comment: Collections don't have a `orderBy` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use **orderByRaw() :**

```
->orderByRaw(
 "order by CASE WHEN total>0 THEN publish_at END DESC, CASE WHEN total>0 THEN total END DESC")
```